How to create unicode anchor in sphinx?
I have a restructured text with chinese title like this
标题
====

and the html will change the title with id=1 like this:
<div class="section" id="id1">
  <h1>标题</h1>
</div>

How can I configure the sphinx to generate html like
<div class="section" id="标题">  <!-- here the id will keep the chinese character unchanged -->
  <h1>标题</h1>
</div>

For exampe: here the anchor for 文件系统 was id2 and url was https://linux-reference.readthedocs.io/zh-cn/latest/README.html#id2. I want to generate url like https://linux-reference.readthedocs.io/zh-cn/latest/README.html#文件系统

It appears that Sphinx does not support Unicode characters in anchors or cross-references. See the reStructuredText specification at https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#reference-names
